# CSS slightly offset to the right - how to correct it?

Tags: html, css, spring, spring-boot, static-libraries

I'm building a Spring Boot + Thymeleaf application using the structure I built for another Spring non-Boot application. While I'm learning a lot, I'm facing a few challenges moslty in setting up Boot structures and displaying the HTML5 pages correctly.

For instance (and this question's topic!) I'm having some CSS problems. Thought I'd rather describe them in text, it's easier to post the following image and explain it further.

[image]

There's a gap between the left-most edge of the sidebar menu to the edge of the screen - which can be seen above and bellow of the bigger vertical line.

Also, the blue horizontal line that "pop's-up" the selected menu is also offset from the left edge.

I haven't developed other templates yet, but I believe they will all follow the same CSS problems.

For CSS and JS, I'm using the [Beyond Admin](https://wrapbootstrap.com/theme/beyondadmin-responisve-admin-app-WB06R48S4) template library from [{wrap}bootstrap](https://wrapbootstrap.com/).

What I've noticed is that all static content are organized inside a folder called `assets` and Spring Boot maps, by default, a folder called `static`.

I have mapped the CSS, image and JS  I use in a file *as per* specified in Thymeleaf documentation. Image files and JS scripts are working as expected, but CSS is not. I'm mapping CSS and JS like bellow:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/css/bootstrap.min.css}" />
<script type="text/javascript" th:src="@{/js/jquery-2.2.3.min.js}"></script>
```

I'm wondering if this odd CSS behavior is related to the folder structure, because in some CSS files there's an explicit reference to the non-existent assets folder.

I have tried to set an `assets` folder to test this, but haven't been able to do it. I tried to do so by adding this line to `application.properties` file.

```
spring.resources.static-locations=classpath:/META-INF/resources/,classpath:/resources/,classpath:/static/**,classpath:/public/**,classpath:/assets/**
```

It didn't work.

My Thymeleaf structure is defined as:

`default.html` -- defines locations for header, sidebar, content and footer

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
          xmlns:layout="http://www.ultraq.net.nz/thymeleaf/layout">

    <head th:include="fragments/common :: commonFragment">
    <link rel="shortcut-icon" th:href="@{/img/favicon.png}" type="image/x-icon" />
    </head>

    <body>
        <div th:id="defaultFragment" th:fragment="defaultFragment">
            <div id="header" th:replace="fragments/header :: headerFragment"></div>
            <div class="main-container container-fluid">
                <div id="sidebar-and-content" class="page-container">
                    <section th:replace="fragments/sidebar :: sidebarFragment"></section>
                    <div class="page-content">
                        <div class="page-body">
                            <section layout:fragment="content"></section>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div th:replace="fragments/footer :: footerFragment"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

`sidebar.html` is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
      xmlns:layout="http://www.ultraq.net.nz/thymeleaf/layout"
      layout:decorator="fragments/default" >

<body th:id="sidebarFragment" th:fragment="sidebarFragment" >
    <div id="sidebar" class="page-sidebar" >
        <!-- Sidebar Menu -->
        <ul class="nav sidebar-menu sidebar-fixed" >
            <li th:if="${#authorization.expression('isAuthenticated()')}" th:classappend="${page == 'menuItem' ? 'active' : ''}">
                <a href="#" th:href="@{/home}"><i class="menu-icon glyphicon glyphicon-home"></i> <span class="menu-text" th:text="#{side.home}"> </span></a>
            </li>
            <li th:if="${#authorization.expression('isAuthenticated()')}" th:classappend="${page == 'menuItem' ? 'active' : ''}">
                <a href="#" th:href="@{#}"><i class="menu-icon glyphicon glyphicon-time"></i> <span class="menu-text" th:text="#{side.menuItem}"> </span></a>
            </li>

            <li th:if="${#authorization.expression('isAuthenticated()')}" th:classappend="${page == 'menuItem' ? 'active' : ''}">
                <a href="#" class="menu-dropdown" th:href="@{#}">
                    <i class="menu-icon glyphicon glyphicon-cog"></i> <span class="menu-text" th:text="#{side.menuItem}"> </span>
                </a>
            </li>

            <li th:if="${#authorization.expression('isAuthenticated()')}" th:classappend="${page == 'menuItem' ? 'active' : ''}">
                <a href="#" th:href="@{#}"><i class="menu-icon glyphicon glyphicon-wrench"></i> <span class="menu-text" th:text="#{side.menuItem}"> </span></a>
            </li>

            <li th:if="${#authorization.expression('isAuthenticated()')}" th:classappend="${page == 'menuItem' ? 'active' : ''}">
                <a href="#" th:href="@{#}"><i class="menu-icon glyphicon glyphicon-wrench"></i> <span class="menu-text" th:text="#{side.menuItem}"> </span></a>
            </li>

            <li th:if="${#authorization.expression('isAuthenticated()')}" th:classappend="${page == 'menuItem' ? 'active' : ''}">
                <a href="#" th:href="@{#}"><i class="menu-icon  glyphicon glyphicon-wrench"></i> <span class="menu-text" th:text="#{side.menuItem}"> </span></a>
            </li>

            <li th:if="${#authorization.expression('isAuthenticated()')}" class="">
                <a class="menu-dropdown" href="#">
                    <i class="menu-icon fa fa-desktop"></i>
                    <span class="menu-text" th:text="#{side.menuItem}"> </span>
                    <i class="menu-expand"></i>
                </a>
                <ul class="submenu" style="display: none;">
                    <li th:if="${#authorization.expression('isAuthenticated()')}" th:classappend="${page == 'menuItem' ? 'active' : ''}">
                        <a href="#" th:href="@{#}"><i class="menu-icon glyphicon glyphicon-wrench"></i> <span class="menu-text" th:text="#{side.menuItem}">Clients </span></a>
                    </li>
                    <li th:if="${#authorization.expression('isAuthenticated()')}" th:classappend="${page == 'menuItem' ? 'active' : ''}">
                        <a href="#" th:href="@{#}"><i class="menu-icon glyphicon glyphicon-wrench"></i> <span class="menu-text" th:text="#{side.menuItem}">Contract </span></a>
                    </li>
                    <li th:if="${#authorization.expression('isAuthenticated()')}" th:classappend="${page == 'menuItem' ? 'active' : ''}">
                        <a href="#" th:href="@{#}"><i class="menu-icon glyphicon glyphicon-wrench"></i> <span class="menu-text" th:text="#{side.menuItem}">Estruturas </span></a>
                    </li>
                    <li th:if="${#authorization.expression('isAuthenticated()')}" th:classappend="${page == 'menuItem' ? 'active' : ''}">
                        <a href="#" th:href="@{#}"><i class="menu-icon glyphicon glyphicon-wrench"></i> <span class="menu-text" th:text="#{side.menuItem}">Cargos </span></a>
                    </li>
                    <li th:if="${#authorization.expression('isAuthenticated()')}" th:classappend="${page == 'menuItem' ? 'active' : ''}">
                        <a href="#" th:href="@{#}"><i class="menu-icon glyphicon glyphicon-wrench"></i> <span class="menu-text" th:text="#{side.menuItem}">Escalas </span></a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>

            <li th:if="${#authorization.expression('hasRole(''ROLE_MASTER'')')}" th:classappend="${page == 'admin' ? 'active' : ''}" class="">
                <a class="menu-dropdown" href="#">
                    <i class="menu-icon fa fa-desktop"></i>
                    <span class="menu-text" th:text="#{side.menuItem}">Admin </span>
                    <i class="menu-expand"></i>
                </a>
                <ul class="submenu" style="display: none;">
                    <li th:if="${#authorization.expression('hasRole(''ROLE_ADMIN'')')}" th:classappend="${page == 'user' ? 'active' : ''}">
                        <a href="#" th:href="@{/admin/user/list}"><i class="menu-icon  glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i> <span class="menu-text" th:text="#{side.menuItem}">Admin </span></a>
                    </li>

                    <li th:if="${#authorization.expression('hasRole(''ROLE_ADMIN'')')}" th:classappend="${page == 'profile' ? 'active' : ''}">
                        <a href="#" th:href="@{/admin/profiles/list}"><i class="menu-icon glyphicon glyphicon-transfer"></i> <span class="menu-text" th:text="#{side.menuItem}">License </span></a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

`header.html` is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">

<body th:id="headerFragment" th:fragment="headerFragment">
    <div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top" >
        <div class="navbar-inner">
            <div class="navbar-container">
                <!-- Navbar Barnd -->
                <div class="navbar-header pull-left">
                    <a href="#" class="navbar-brand"> <small> <img
                            th:src="@{/img/cn_small.png}" alt="" />
                    </small>
                    </a>
                </div>
                <!-- /Navbar Barnd -->
                <!-- Sidebar Collapse -->
                <div class="sidebar-collapse" id="sidebar-collapse">
                    <i class="collapse-icon fa fa-bars"></i>
                </div>

                <div class="navbar-header pull-right">
                    <div class="navbar-account">
                        <ul class="account-area">
                            <li class="">
                                <a class="login-area dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                                    <section>
                                        <h2>
                                            <span class="profile">
                                                <strong><span th:text="${#authentication.name}" >authentication.name</span></strong>
                                            </span>
                                        </h2>
                                    </section>
                                </a>
                                <!-- Login Area Dropdown -->
                                <ul class="pull-right dropdown-menu dropdown-arrow dropdown-login-area">
                                    <li class="username"><a><span class="setting" th:text="${#authentication.name}" ></span></a></li>
                                    <!--Theme Selector Area-->
                                    <li class="theme-area">
                                        <ul class="colorpicker" id="skin-changer">
                                            <li><a class="colorpick-btn" href="#" style="background-color:#8C0095;" th:rel="@{/css/skins/purple.min.css}"></a></li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </li>
                                    <!--/Theme Selector Area-->
                                    <li th:if="${#authorization.expression('isAuthenticated()')}" class="dropdown-footer">
                                        <a href="/logout" th:href="@{/logout}" th:text="#{gen.logout}">Logout</a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                        <div class="setting">
                            <a id="btn-setting" th:title="#{gen.settings}">
                                <i class="icon glyphicon glyphicon-cog"></i>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="setting-container">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Why is CSS offset? What is wrong here?

Comment: Could you possibly provide a demo? With the rendered HTML.

Comment: Looks like you have a `ul` inside `li` element, which might cause the indentation (both `ul` and `li` elements has margin/padding values). Without a working demo it will be hard to help, but my guess will be that `#sidebar ul, #sidebar li {margin: 0; padding: 0;}` will solve this.

Comment: This works without any glitch on the non-spring boot project. As far as I can tell, the only difference is the location for the css folder. I'll give your suggestion a go, though.

Comment: The location for the CSS folder can affect the loading of the css files/values :)

Comment: Yeah! I thought so! So, how to add another location to the classpath?